# Passing many variables from a function in one class to a function in another class

Tags: c++

I am creating a chess engine using bitboards and I have two classes: `class Board` and `class Evaluation`.

There are many variables in the `Board` class that I want to pass to a **function** in the `Evaluation` class. This class evaluates the position of the Board and returns a number. I want to pass all my bitboards to this class. They are around 15 in number and may even increase.

I will be creating an object of the `Evaluation` class in the `Board` class and from the `Board` class I will be calling the `boardEvaluation` function. It is to this function that I want to pass these bitboards.

One way to do this is to simply accept 15 arguments in the function I want to pass the variables to. However, I would prefer not using this approach since it does not sound appealing.

Is there any other way to pass so many variables from one class to a function in another class?

Comment: I'm glad you spotted it wasn't appealing. Split the `Board` class into presentation data and content data and pass the latter into the `Evaluation` methods.

Comment: Why don't you just make your evaluation function a member of the Board class?

Comment: That is a good option but I would have to change many things in my engine and I will do it only if I run out of options.

Comment: @AdrianMay I would, but I am planning to add many functions in the `Evaluation` class like discovering pawn structure and such things, which I believe would rather not be mixed with the Board class. I will go for it only when all else fails.

Comment: Who said anything about removing the Evaluation class? You could put doEvaluation into Board and let it return an Evaluation, or you could pass the whole Board to Evaluation::doEvaluation(), or you could have a global that takes both. At the end of the day, "this" is only an implicit parameter, so it doesn't make much difference. But you asked how to avoid passing 15 parameters and the answer is to pass a pointer to the Board, either implicitly or explicitly. If you really want to, you can take Wojtek's advice to internally restructure Board and only pass a portion of it, but why bother?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create another class `BoardData` and use it in both `Board` and `Evaluation`. The responsibility of `BoardData` would be to store your 15 variables - and maybe provide some basic operations on them. In this way your design will be simplified without circural depependencies.

Comment: We know of ONE function that doesn't require ALL of the variables in Board, and for that reason you'd make a new class?

Comment: Yes - the alternative would be to give up on `Evaluation` class and incorporate it into `Board`, and it might be wrong choice - maybe it is worth to keep board evaluation separate.

Comment: I didn't hear any reason for Evaluation to exist either. This is what went wrong with C++: people think "do the complicated thing unless you can prove the simple thing will work." I think "do the simple thing unless you can prove the simple thing won't work."

Comment: Your alternative is to use one class for everything. Yes, it would work. Is is the best design for long term? I do not think so. Separation between Board and Evaluation is very natural to me.

Comment: Neither of us knows enough about Evaluation to say whether it's justified or not, but in the first place I wasn't talking about Evaluation. I was saying that BoardData is overkill if its only for the sake of one function. boardEvaluation() could be a member of Board returning an Evaluation for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps:

1. `boardEvaluation` function can have `Board*` as it's argument
2. The function being `friend` of the `Board` class.
3. Then in the `Evaluation.h` header file forward declare the `Board` class
4. Use the 15 private member variables of `Board` class directly in the function.

Having said that, when the design comes to the point that you are about to use `friend` you probably need to reconsider your original design and relationships between the two classes.
In your case, you may probably need to move the `boardEvaluation` to the `Board` class instead, if possible.